# Как обновить Arch Linux с LiveUSB?

Tags: archlinux

У меня полетел Arch Linux. Подскажите, как я могу обновить систему, если я сейчас загрузился с LiveUSB?

По сути мне нужно запустить команду `pacman` на локальной ОС.

Comment: Сделать chroot в интересующую систему, в интернете инструкций полно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала примонтируйте корневой раздел «полетевшей» ОС:

```bsh
mount <root-partition> <mount-point>
```

Затем выполните

```bsh
arch-chroot <mount-point>
```

И, наконец, для полного обновления «полетевшей» системы выполните

```bsh
pacman -Syu
```

Comment: А где мне посмотреть расположение корневого раздела?

Comment: @ЕгорКозельский `fdisk -l` покажет список устройств и размеченных разделов.

Comment: Зайти получилось. Но вылезла ошибка при обновлении.
error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
error: could not determine filesystem mount points
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
_______________
Commands:
mount /dev/nvkp1p1
chroot /dev/nvkp1p1 /mnt
pacman -Syu

Comment: @ЕгорКозельский, вы уверены, что примонтировали нужный раздел?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot#Mount_the_partitions

Вот эти команды помогли

Comment: @ЕгорКозельский, вы, случайно, не просто `chroot` запускали?

Comment: я использовал chroot. нo требовалось еще примонтировать другие разделы

Comment: @ЕгорКозельский, если бы вы использовали `arch-chroot`, то этого не понадобилось бы, т. к. этот скрипт делает это за вас.

Comment: command 'arch-chroot' was not found :(

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot#Mount_the_partitions

```
# cd /mnt
# mount -t proc /proc proc/
# mount --rbind /sys sys/
# mount --rbind /dev dev/
# cp /etc/resolv.conf etc/resolv.conf
# chroot /mnt /bin/bash
# pacman -Syu
```

Вот эти команды помогли